# Does not receive broadcast when application killed in vivo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, overlay, broadcast

I would like to show overlay when incoming call received in my Vivo phone but when I killed application from the background it does not receive broadcast and unable to show overlay dialog.

Comment: Have you tested on other devices? Is the behavior is same on all devices?

Comment: Yes, I have tested with other devices, and its working fine but not on my vivo phone

Comment: I also faced these type of issues on Oppo devices. Its seems like some restrictions from operating system modified by specific mobile company. I also tried service to resolve my problem but again oppo killed that service too when we kill app. Finally i got solution with WorkManager, I use workmanager for all background tasks and it worked like charm. Workmanager take cares for every thing like OS versions, old os compatibility etc it automatically started when we turn on phone after switching off. You can also add constraints like internet connectivity and many more.